# Quip Live App OAUTH2 auth.login() promise never resolving

Tags: quip

I have setup an auth config for Asana.

I am using a slightly modified `google-drive` example.

After clicking login, a popup appears, then closes, but the promise never resolves or rejects.

When I check the `auth` object, I can see that the minified property `Ni` is a `Promise` whose `[[PromiseStatus]] = "pending"`.

What could be the issue?

How can I debug further?

---

When diving into the obfuscated source, `auth.login` returns a `Promise.all` of two promisew.

[image]

The first promise `b` resolves after the popup window closes. But the second promise `var f = b3(this, n(this.Ej, this));` never resolves.

What could the problem be?

---

Seems that the issue is that this event listener is never called. Placing a breakpoint inside `function f()` is never reached.

This listener unobfuscates to: `quip.apps.addEventListener(quip.apps.EventType.USER_PREFERENCE_UPDATE, f);`

So the questions is: why does `USER_PREFERENCE_UPDATE` not trigger, and why is this needed?

[image]

---

So printing `quip.apps.getUserPreferences()` returns:

[image]

The auth data is stored in the user preferences.

[image]

So here we see that there is a `Server Error`. Not sure where it comes from, whether it is from Quip or Asana.

So this looks like the core issue. The `auth_data` setup in the Quip Console is not being retrieved properly from the backend.

This data seems to be server-side rendered with the initial page load. So it seems like a backend bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was using an incorrect token url.

Still, the error handling for Quip Live Apps should provide a better error message.

And also, the Test Login button only tests the authorization url, not the token url.